# How to pass parameter to a scrapy pipeline object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

After scraping some data with a Scrapy spider:

```
class Test_Spider(Spider):

    name = "test"
    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(900,902,1):
            ........
            yield item
```

I pass the data to a pipeline object to be written to an SQLite table using SQLAlchemy::

```
class SQLlitePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        _engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")
        _connection = _engine.connect()
        _metadata = MetaData()
        _stack_items = Table("table1", _metadata,
                             Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                             Column("detail_url", Text),
        _metadata.create_all(_engine)
        self.connection = _connection
        self.stack_items = _stack_items

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        is_valid = True
```

I'd like to be able to set the table name as a variable instead of being hardcoded in as it is now `"table1"`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you pass this parameter through the command line (e.g. `-s table="table1"`), define a `from_crawler` method.

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
    settings = crawler.settings
    table = settings.get('table')

    # Instantiate the pipeline with your table
    return cls(table)

def __init__(self, table):
    _engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")
    _connection = _engine.connect()
    _metadata = MetaData()
    _stack_items = Table(table, _metadata,
                         Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                         Column("detail_url", Text),
    _metadata.create_all(_engine)
    self.connection = _connection
    self.stack_items = _stack_items
```

Comment: Thank you very much. can the table be set from inside the spider?

Comment: Yep, you'd open your connection inside `open_spider` (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#open_spider) instead of `__init__`.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler way to do this is to pass the argument on `crawl`:

```
scrapy crawl -a table=table1
```

Then get the value with `spider.table`:

```
class TestScrapyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        table = spider.table
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class SQLlitePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self, table_name):

        _engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")
        _connection = _engine.connect()
        _metadata = MetaData()
        _stack_items = Table(table_name, _metadata,
                             Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                             Column("detail_url", Text),
        _metadata.create_all(_engine)
        self.connection = _connection
        self.stack_items = _stack_items

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        table_name = getattr(crawler.spider, 'table_name')
        return cls(table_name)
```

With `from_crawler` you can create or instantiate a pipeline object with the parameters you specify.