# Classmethod from_crawler in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the relationship between a pipeline and crawler in scrapy, after asking my last question ([How to pass parameter to a scrapy pipeline object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043970/how-to-pass-parameter-to-a-scrapy-pipeline-object))

One of the answers was:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
    settings = crawler.settings
    table = settings.get('table')

    # Instantiate the pipeline with your table
    return cls(table)

def __init__(self, table):
    _engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")
    _connection = _engine.connect()
    _metadata = MetaData()
    _stack_items = Table(table, _metadata,
                         Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                         Column("detail_url", Text),
    _metadata.create_all(_engine)
    self.connection = _connection
    self.stack_items = _stack_items
```

I am confused about:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
    settings = crawler.settings
    table = settings.get('table')
```

Does the crawler class already exist or are we creating it here. Can someone explain what is happening here in more detail? I have been reading through a number of sources including http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api.html#crawler-api and http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/architecture.html , but I'm not putting the pieces together yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's me again :)

Maybe what you didn't get is the meaning of `classmethod` in Python. In your case, it's a method that belongs to your `SQLlitePipeline` class. Thus, the `cls` is the `SQLlitePipeline` class itself.

Scrapy calls this pipeline method passing the `crawler` object, which Scrapy instantiates by itself. Up to this point, **we still don't have an `SQLlitePipeline` instance yet**. In other words, the pipeline flow hasn't started yet.

After getting the desired parameter (`table`) from the crawler's settings, `from_crawler` finally returns an **instance of the pipeline** by doing `cls(table)` (remember what `cls` is, right? So, it's the same as doing `SQLlitePipeline(table)`).

This is a plain Python object instantiation, so `__init__` will be called with the table name it's expecting, and then the pipeline flow will start.

**EDIT**

Maybe it's good to have an overview on the process executed by Scrapy, step by step. Of course it's much more complex than what I will illustrate, but hopefully it'll give you a better understanding.

1) You invoke Scrapy

2) Scrapy instantiates a `crawler` object

```
crawler = Crawler(...)
```

3) Scrapy identifies the pipeline class you want to use (`SQLlitePipeline`) and calls its `from_crawler` method.

```
# Note that SQLlitePipeline is not instantiated here, as from_crawler is a class method
# However, as we saw before, this method returns an instance of the pipeline class
pipeline_instance = SQLlitePipeline.from_crawler(crawler)
```

4) From this point on, it calls the pipeline instance methods listed [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline)

```
pipeline_instance.open_spider(...)
pipeline_instance.process_item(...)
pipeline_instance.close_spider(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Lucas, that helps me a lot! I have been rereading some explanations of @classmethod in python but I still don't understand the 'crawler' parameter in 'def from_crawler(cls, crawler)'. Could you please expand on this?

Comment: It's an object that Scrapy instantiates by itself when it's doing its things and passes to the `from_crawler` method, no need to worry about how it's done. It's good to know about its attributes, though, but it's all in the docs that you linked in the question. More specifically here: http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler

Comment: Sorry, not explaining myself well. I have been reading about the crawler object, but with regard to the @staticmethod  'def from_crawler(cls, crawler)' you said : 'Scrapy calls this pipeline method passing the crawler object'. Is the crawler object instantiated inside the SQLlitePipeline object, I haven't seen this pattern before.

Comment: Also I did previously look at http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler. However I don't see the connection to the pipeline instance. As far as I can see they say : 'The Crawler object must be instantiated with a scrapy.spiders.Spider subclass and a scrapy.settings.Settings object.' I don't think that is happening here.

Comment: It does happen, but it's transparent as Scrapy does it all internally :) see my updated answer to see if it clarifies the process a bit.

Comment: After reading your answer I realized that pipelines have a from_crawler method and found https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html . Now its making more sense. Thank you again.