# How to set crawler parameter from scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

I am trying to pass a db table parameter set in a scrapy spider to a pipeline object to follow up question [How to pass parameter to a scrapy pipeline object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043970/how-to-pass-parameter-to-a-scrapy-pipeline-object). based on the answer to this question I have:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    # Here, you get whatever value was passed through the "table" parameter
    settings = crawler.settings
    table = settings.get('table')

    # Instantiate the pipeline with your table
    return cls(table)

def __init__(self, table):
    _engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")
    _connection = _engine.connect()
    _metadata = MetaData()
    _stack_items = Table(table, _metadata,
                         Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                         Column("detail_url", Text),
    _metadata.create_all(_engine)
    self.connection = _connection
    self.stack_items = _stack_items
```

My spider looks like:

```
class my_Spider(Spider):

    name = "my"

    def from_crawler(self, crawler, table='test'):
        pass


    def start_requests(self):

       .....
```

I added the from_crawler line based on https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.from_crawler , but now I'm getting:

```
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 94, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unbound method from_crawler() must be called with My_Spider instance as first argument (got Crawler instance instead)
```

How can I get this working?

EDIT :

after changing the class method I'm getting:

```
exceptions.TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
2016-12-09 15:47:37 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\ENVS\virtalenvs\contact\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 36, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\ENVS\r2\my\my\pipelines.py", line 30, in from_crawler
    return cls(table_name)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to pass parameters to the running spider (when you call `scrapy crawl myspider`), you just need to specify it with the `-a` argument in shell:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a arg1=value1
```

so if you have a spider class:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
```

This `arg1` argument will be passed as an actual argument to that spider instance, which means you will be able to use it anywhere on that class:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "myspider"

    ...

    def some_callback_method(self, response):
        print self.arg1
        ...
```

No need to set `from_crawler` in the actual spider.

The pipeline also receives a spider instance, and you are already using it there.

**UPDATE:**

Now in your `pipeline` you are not really using a "spider attribute", but a variable in scrapy settings. If you want to pass the table name as a spider argument (so to use `-a` from command line), you have to change your pipeline to:

```
...
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    table_name = getattr(crawler.spider, "table")
    return cls(table_name)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. So what would I pass as the argument if I want to call the table 'test' given the pipeline classmethod as written above ?

Comment: ok sorry, you were not using a spider argument in your pipeline, you were using settings, please check my updated answer.

Comment: remove the `from_crawler` of the spider, you only need it on the `pipeline`

Comment: had already done that. I'm running 'scrapy crawl j1 -a table=value1' In my editor I am seeing that 'tablename' is not recognized - -- please see screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130259/discussion-between-elrull-and-user61629).